# Realm Migration: Move an Object from one Object to another Object

Tags: swift3, realm, realm-migration

I have three objects:

```
class Customer: Object {
    dynamic var solution: Solution!;
    ...
}

class Solution: Object {
    dynamic var data: Data!;
    ...
}

class Data: Object {
    ...
}
```

Now i need to move the `Data` Object from `Solution` to `Customer` so that it becomes:

```
class Customer: Object {
    dynamic var solution: Solution!;
    dynamic var data: Data!;
    ...
}
```

I have no idea how I have to implement my Realm Migration method so that everything works fine and that I wont lose data.

Answer (score 2):

I did some experiments with the Realm migrations sample app and came up with this potential solution:

In a migration block, you can only interact with your Realm file via the `migration` object. Any attempts to directly access the Realm file mid-migration will result in an exception.

That being said, it's possible to have nested calls to `migration.enumerateObjects` referencing different Realm model object classes. As such, it should simply be a matter of initially enumerating through the `Customer` objects, and in each iteration, enumerate through the `Solution` objects to find the corresponding one with the right `data` value. Once found, it should be possible to set the `Customer` object with the data from the `Solution` object.

```
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(
    schemaVersion: 1,
    migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
        if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {
            migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: Customer.className()) { oldCustomerObject, newCustomerObject in
                migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: Solution.className()) { oldSolutionObject, newSolutionObject in
                    //Check that the solution object is the one referenced by the customer
                    guard oldCustomerObject["solution"].isEqual(oldSolutionObject) else { return }
                    //Copy the data
                    newCustomerObject["data"] = oldSolutionObject["data"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

I feel I need to stress that this code is by no means tested and guaranteed to work in its present state. So I recommend you make sure you thoroughly test it on some dummy data you wouldn't miss beforehand. :)

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4, Realm 3

I had to migrate a Realm object that linked to another object. I wanted to remove the explicit link and replace it with an object ID. TiM's solution got me most of the way there, and just needed a little refinement.

```
   var config = Realm.Configuration()
   config.migrationBlock = { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
        if oldSchemaVersion < CURRENT_SCHEMA_VERSION {

            // enumerate the first object type
            migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: Message.className()) { (oldMsg, newMsg) in 

                // extract the linked object and cast from Any to DynamicObject
                if let msgAcct = oldMsg?["account"] as? DynamicObject {

                    // enumerate the 2nd object type
                    migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: Account.className()) { (oldAcct, newAcct) in
                        if let oldAcct = oldAcct {

                             // compare the extracted object to the enumerated object
                             if msgAcct.isEqual(oldAcct) {

                                // success!
                                newMsg?["accountId"] = oldAcct["accountId"]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```